# notifyDataSetChanged being called prevents user interaction (Android development)

Tags: android

I have a problem where calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` a bunch of times will freeze interaction with a listview for a brief second.

Basically my app loads a bunch of images into a listview. After each is loaded it posts to the ui thread. The ui thread adds the image to a listarray and then calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

When you select an image in the list it highlights. When I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` per image, every one of three taps on the list might actually select. If I throttle down `notifyDataSetChanged()`, I get a much better rate of tapping and having it select the item.

Anyone have hints on this?

It seems like the 6 thumbs visible (which are unchanged) get thrown out really quick and swapped in again, but the UI shows no indication of them being deleted. During which tapping is an invalid data set.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call notifyDataSetChange() in the UI Thread. it will definitely block the User interaction if it is doing the data call and update the ListView. so do it in the AsyncTask do in background thread which is not doing on the UI thread so it will update the listview when user scroll it

Comment: I was using code similar to this. I am pretty sure it crashed when I moved the notifyDataSetChange and setting of the image to the worker, maybe I just needed to try only moving the notifyDataSetChange. My code is most similar to this example: http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/11/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html

Comment: I fixed this problem by creating a custom control that draws all the images via a surface view - way way faster and I can save memory, not have the wonky selection issues either.